# Run time error if last array value is negative

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have this short piece of code, its purpose is to sum negative values and count positive ones, the vector is initialized else where

```
;sum all negative values and count positive values 
    ;let eax hold sum and ebx hold number of positives 
    CALL crlf
    mov ecx, VectorSize
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov edx, 0
    sumMe: 
        cmp Vector[edx * TYPE Vector], 0
        jge pos
        ;neg
        add eax, Vector[edx * TYPE Vector]
        INC edx
        loop sumMe 
        pos:
            INC ebx 
            INC edx
            loop sumMe
```

The piece of code works correctly except when a negative value is the last value in the array, even something like `-1 -1 -1 -1 5` works. However if I have a negative value in the last location the program crashes.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: With the code you've shown, there's nothing after the loop so your program will always crash when it decodes/executes whatever garbage bytes are next when it eventually leaves the loop.  This isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes I print the contents of eax and ebx then exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's a `ret` or something at the end:

What does `loop` do when ecx reaches zero: execution falls through.  If the last element was negative, the `loop` instruction that makes `ecx` zero is followed by `pos:`.

When `loop` runs with `ecx=0` to start with, `ecx` wraps to `0xFFFFFFFF` and the jump is taken.  `loop` is like the bottom of a `do{}while(--ecx);`.

All of this would be obvious if you used a debugger to single-step that last iteration, because you already know the problem is at the end of the array with a negative element.

Comment: Changing out the first `loop` to an unconditional jump to the second `loop` did the trick, thanks

Comment: @Mitchel0022: That would make it a bit more like an if/else, but the loop tail-duplication you had before was more efficient.  (Although [`loop` itself is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently) and should generally be avoided).  The simple fix is to put a `jmp` *after* the first `loop`, so that exit-from-loop path goes where you want, without adding any instructions inside the loop.  Of course, there are plenty of other efficiency improvements I could suggest, like branchless or one load...